# show vim command keys on live demo

Tags: linux, vim

I'm going to make a live presentation showing vim capabilities. It's essential to show the audience command keys that I press. I know I can use `showcmd`, but I find its output to small and to hard to notice to use it in live demo. Is there any way to make it easier to notice? It could be something similar to command keys shown in Railscasts (for instance in [this video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4), 1:11). Do you know anything like that?

Comment: What OS are you using? This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529329/

Comment: I use Ubuntu Linux with Gnome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For X11, there is [key mon](http://code.google.com/p/key-mon/). I'm sure there are similar tools for other systems. Otherwise, you could use some sort of virtual keyboard which also shows keypresses.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a recent vimcast article about Drew Neil tackling the same issue  -
[Vimprint Source](https://github.com/nelstrom/vimprint), [Article](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/05/vimprint---a-vim-keystroke-parser/)

Relevant accompanying talk -
[Video](https://vimeo.com/67215273), [Slides](https://speakerdeck.com/nelstrom/vimprint-a-vim-keystroke-parser)

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Screenkey](http://seminar.io/projects/screenkey/), inspired from key-mon.